# Adding borders to rows and columns with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

How can I add borders to whole rows and columns with openpyxl?

I tried:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import borders
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

border1 = borders.Side(style = None, color = Color(indexed = 0), border_style = 'thin')
border0 = borders.Side(style = None, color = None, border_style = None)
thin = Border(left = border1, right = border0, bottom = border0, top = border 0)

ws.column['C'].border = thin
```

I then got the Error:

```
Worksheet object has no attribute column
```

Is there a possibility to assign the border to whole row/column or do I need to apply it to the cells one by one?

Comment: As it says it the documentation: you must always format all the cells one by one.

Comment: There is no such entity of row/column (a column is just a list/tuple of cells). There are cells. Simply iterate over a specific column/row and set the style to each cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example how to iterate through the cells to aplly the border to each cell. min_col = 3 and max_col = 3 leads to column 'C' and with max_row you can set till which row you want the border.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import borders
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('border.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

border1 = borders.Side(style = None, color = 'FF000000', border_style = 'thin')
border0 = borders.Side(style = None, color = None, border_style = None)
thin = Border(left = border1, right = border0, bottom = border0, top = border0)

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=3, max_row=20, max_col=3):
    for cell in row:
        cell.border = thin
        
wb.save('border_new.xlsx')
```